# Typo in Lovett's Abstract Algebra regarding group action on itself?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image]

Should the "left conjugation" be fixed to left multiplication? I searched for left conjugation but nothing came up.

Also, why is it important that $g(xH) = (gx)H$ is another left coset?

Finally, can I summarize the results of group action on itself by left multiplication as follows?

> $H\leq G$ iff left cosets form a system of blocks.
>
> $H \unlhd G$ iff right cosets form a system of blocks.

If there is anything I can add, or should fix, please let me know!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Lovett should have written *left multiplication* there.

One reason why we care that $g(xH)$ is another left coset is because we might want to define an action of $G$ on $G/H$, the set of left cosets of $H$, by left multiplication. To do so, we first have to show that this action is well defined — that is, to show that left multiplication of a coset is again a coset.

In this particular context, Lovett is describing the action of $G$ on itself by left multiplication, and telling you about the structure of the action. It’s a transitive action, and it has a system of blocks — a partition of $G$ which is permuted by the action — given by left cosets of $H$.